# Agrupar select e retornar quantidade exata

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Pessoal estou usando o entity e tenho uma consulta que retorna umas 2000 linhas. Após fazer isso:

```
base.Get(queryParameters)
.GroupBy(x => new { x.Id })
```

Até ai está normal,eu trabalho com pagedlist, onde é informado o número da página que vai ser exibida e a quantidade de itens dela, exemplo:

-O retorno tem 20 itens, é informado page 2 e quantidade 10, o retorno vai ser 10 itens do 11º até o 20º item da lista.

O problema é que só consigo fazer depois de ter feito a consulta das 2000 linhas no banco e agrupado elas, o que faz com que a demora seja muito grande, pois existem alguns 'joins' no meio.

Existe alguma forma de agrupar uma query e dar o paged nela antes que a consulta seja feita no banco?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766300/pagedlist-with-entity-framework-getting-all-records

Answer (score 0):

Monte sua `IQueryable<T>` antes de chamar o método `ToList()` que será convertido para uma query SQL que provavelmente executará mais rápido do que um agrupamento dentro da memória.

Answer (score 0):

Você teria que saber a pagina atual antes de fazer o ToList(),
algo como :

```
int numeroDeObjPorPagina = 10;

base.Get(queryParameters)
.GroupBy(x => new { x.Id })
.Skip(numeroDeObjPorPagina * paginaAtual)
.Take(numeroDeObjPorPagina)
.ToList();
```